# WPF ListView Binding

Tags: wpf

I have a list view that is hooked to an Observable collection as it's ItemsSource.
I keep getting collection must be empty being using ItemsSource.
Is this because I'm specifying the columns I want in the XMAL?

If so how would I make sure the IsChecked value is a checkbox and the rest text?

XMAL

```
<ListView x:Name="lstNextGen" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="430" Margin="10,95,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="793">
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding IsChecked}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PatientName}" Header="Patient Name" Width="300px" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DOB}" Header="D.O.B." Width="75px" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AppointmentDate}" Header="Appointment Date" Width="150" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DocumentType}" Header="Document Type" Width="150px" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the style for the child items using the `ItemContainerStyle` otherwise it will be considered as child item and will be added to `Items` collection.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstNextGen" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="430" Margin="10,95,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="793">
          <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Tag="{Binding IsChecked}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PatientName}" Header="Patient Name" Width="300px" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DOB}" Header="D.O.B." Width="75px" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AppointmentDate}" Header="Appointment Date" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DocumentType}" Header="Document Type" Width="150px" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I used this exact same implementation to achieve Style Triggers for my Checkbox controls. Works great!